# Zend Framework 2 - Hydrator strategy for Doctrine relationship not working

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-form, zend-framework2, foreign-key-relationship

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14140447/1331671) I'm building a custom hydration strategy to handle my related objects in a select box in a form.

My form looks like this:

```
$builder = new AnnotationBuilder($entityManager);
$form    = $builder->createForm(new MyEntity());
$form->add(new MyFieldSet());

$hydrator = new ClassMethodsHydrator();
$hydrator->addStrategy('my_attribute', new MyHydrationStrategy());
$form->setHydrator($hydrator);

$form->get('my_attribute')->setValueOptions(
      $entityManager->getRepository('SecEntity\Entity\SecEntity')->fetchAllAsArray()
);
```

**When I add a new `MyEntity` via the `addAction` everything works great.**

I wrote `fetchAllAsArray()` to populate my selectbox. It lives within my SecEntityRepository:

```
public function fetchAllAsArray() {

    $objects = $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
        ->add('select', 's.id, s.name')
        ->add('orderBy', 's.name ASC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();

    $list = array();
    foreach($objects as $obj) {
        $list[$obj['id']] = $obj['name'];
    }

    return $list;
}
```

But in the edit-case the `extract()` function doesn't work. I'm not at the point where I see something of `hydrate()` so I'll leave it out for now.

My hydrator strategy looks like this:

```
class MyHydrationStrategy extends DefaultStrategy
{
    public function extract($value) {        
        print_r($value);
        $result = array();
        foreach ($value as $instance) {
            print_r($instance);
            $result[] = $instance->getId();
        }
        return $result;
    }

    public function hydrate($value) {
        ...
    }
```

The problem is as follows:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object

The `print_r($value)` returns loads of stuff beginning with

> DoctrineORMModule\Proxy__CG__\SecEntity\Entity\SecEntity Object

following with something about BasicEntityPersister and somewhere in the mess are my referenced entities.

The `print_r($instance)` prints nothing. It's just empty. Therefore I guess is the error message legit... but why can't I iterate over these objects?

Any ideas?

**Edit:**

Regarding to @Sam:

My attribute in the entity:

```
    /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Path/To/Entity", inversedBy="whatever")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="attribute_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * @Form\Attributes({"type":"hidden"})
 *
 */
protected $attribute;
```

My new selectbox:

```
$form->add(array(
        'name'       => 'attribute',
        'type'       => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect',
        'attributes' => array(
            'required' => true
        ),
        'options'    => array(
            'label'           => 'MyLabel',
            'object_manager'  => $entityManager,
            'target_class'    => 'Path/To/Entity',
            'property'        => 'name'
        )
    ));
```

My final hope is that I'm doing something wrong within the controller. Neither my selectbox is preselected nor the value is saved...

```
...

$obj= $this->getEntityManager()->find('Path/To/Entity', $id);

    $builder = new \MyEnity\MyFormBuilder();
    $form = $builder->newForm($this->getEntityManager());

    $form->setBindOnValidate(false);
    $form->bind($obj);
    $form->setData($obj->getArrayCopy());

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $form->setData($request->getPost());

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $form->bindValues();
            $this->getEntityManager()->flush();

            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('entity');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Question: Why do you not use the Doctrine Form Elements?

Comment: Good one :) I'm not aware of their existence I have to admit... do you know a good tutorial for them? if they work it's a legit answer for this question I'd say ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I still haven't come around to write the tutorial for that :S

I don't know if this is working with the annotationbuilder though! As the `DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect` needs the `EntityManager` to work. The options for the `ObjectSelect` are as follows:

```
   $this->add(array(
        'name'       => 'formElementName',
        'type'       => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect',
        'attributes' => array(
            'required' => true
        ),
        'options'    => array(
            'label'           => 'formElementLabel',
            'empty_option'    => '--- choose formElementName ---',
            'object_manager'  => $this->getEntityManager(),
            'target_class'    => 'Mynamespace\Entity\Entityname',
            'property'        => 'nameOfEntityPropertyAsSelect'
        )
    ));
```

In this case i make use of `$this->getEntityManager()`. I set up this dependency when calling the form from the ServiceManager. Personally i always do this from FactoryClasses. My FormFactory looks like this:

```
public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
{
    $em = $serviceLocator->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');

    $form = new ErgebnishaushaltProduktForm('ergebnisform', array(
        'entity_manager' => $em
    ));

    $classMethodsHydrator = new ClassMethodsHydrator(false);

    // Wir fügen zwei Strategien, um benutzerdefinierte Logik während Extrakt auszuführen
    $classMethodsHydrator->addStrategy('produktBereich', new Strategy\ProduktbereichStrategy())
                         ->addStrategy('produktGruppe', new Strategy\ProduktgruppeStrategy());

    $hydrator = new DoctrineEntity($em, $classMethodsHydrator);

    $form->setHydrator($hydrator)
         ->setObject(new ErgebnishaushaltProdukt())
         ->setInputFilter(new ErgebnishaushaltProduktFilter())
         ->setAttribute('method', 'post');

    return $form;
}
```

And this is where all the magic is happening. Magic, that is also relevant to your other Thread here on SO. First, i grab the `EntityManager`. Then i create my form, and inject the dependency for the `EntityManager`. I do this using my own Form, you may write and use a Setter-Function to inject the `EntityManager`.

Next i create a `ClassMethodsHydrator` and add two `HydrationStrategies` to it. Personally i need to apply those strategies for each `ObjectSelect`-Element. You **may not have to** do this on your side. Try to see if it is working without it first!

After that, i create the `DoctrineEntity`-Hydrator, inject the `EntityManager` as well as my custom `ClassMethodsHydrator`. This way the Strategies will be added easily.

The rest should be quite self-explanatory (despite the german classnames :D)

**Why the need for strategies**

Imo, this is something missing from the `DoctrineEntity` currently, but things are still in an early stage. And once [DoctrineModule-Issue#106](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/pull/106) will be live, things will change again, probably making it more comfortable.

A Strategy looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace Haushaltportal\Stdlib\Hydrator\Strategy;

use Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\Strategy\StrategyInterface;

class ProduktbereichStrategy implements StrategyInterface
{
    public function extract($value)
    {
        if (is_numeric($value) || $value === null) {
            return $value;
        }

        return $value->getId();
    }

    public function hydrate($value)
    {
        return $value;
    }
}
```

So whenever the `$value` is not numeric or null, meaning: it should be an Object, we will call the `getId()` function. Personally i think it's a good idea to give each Element it's own strategy, but if you are sure you won't be needing to change the strategy at a later point, you could create a global Strategy for several elements like `DefaultGetIdStrategy` or something.

All this is basically the good work of [Michael Gallego aka Bakura](http://michaelgallego.fr/)! In case you drop by the IRC, just hug him once ;)

**Edit** An additional resource with a [look into the future](https://github.com/bakura10/DoctrineModule/blob/a76195401d8f9fbc2c32e4435edf889793a1d6c8/docs/hydrator.md) - updated hydrator-docs for a very likely, soon to be included, pull request

Comment: even without the strategy no error occurs and everything looks fine but in the edit case it wont save/overwrite the foreign key. even if the correct one is in the `POST` AND in the form after binding! adding your strategy doesnt change it... ideas?

Comment: Do you include the ID in your form? Will be hard to tell without the whole code otherwise.

Comment: oddest thing ever! I altered my controller and set the formElement value manually to my `id` and after `bindValues()` also manually to my object again. it works...! very ugly but until then I'm unfortunately forced to stick to this solution.

Comment: Sry for my late reply, fell asleep :D `bindValues()`, you fetch the object from the DB, like `$ent = $repo->find(1)` and then bind it to the form via `$form->bind($ent)`. Using this all getter function will be called, populating the form with identical element names.

Comment: so i'd need to alter my getter/setter for the FKs to handle id vs object?