# Add option to form element in the controller

Tags: php, annotations, zend-form, zend-framework2, zend-form-element

Related to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14142488/1331671) I want to transform a manual adding of a form element to `Annotations` in my `Entity`.

The code looks like this:

```
$this->add(array(
    'name'       => 'formElementName',
    'type'       => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect',
    'attributes' => array(
        'required' => true
    ),
    'options'    => array(
        'label'           => 'formElementLabel',
        'empty_option'    => '--- choose formElementName ---',
        'object_manager'  => $this->getEntityManager(),
        'target_class'    => 'Mynamespace\Entity\Entityname',
        'property'        => 'nameOfEntityPropertyAsSelect'
    )
));
```

As an annotation I have the problem that the `object_manager` is a variable which I cannot pass to annotations. Every other attribute is no problem and should work when being annotated.

I'm looking for the correct way to do this:

```
$form->get('formElementName').setOptions(array('object_manager'=>$entityManager)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Just as comment since i'm not 100% sure. But the `object_manager` will be needed upon element instantiation. Meaning: Once the Form is constructed. Therefore you won't be able to set the entityManager like this at a later point. You may have to add the whole `ObjectSelect` from the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to try this it will working fine.

```
<!-- language-all: lang-html -->
foreach($cityArr as $city){

  $city_ar[$city['id']] = $city['city'];

}

$form->user_city->setMultiOptions($city_ar);

$form->user_city->setValue($val["user_city"]);
```