# zf2 forms don't set value in composed object

Tags: forms, doctrine-orm, annotations, zend-framework2, entity

I have problem with ZF2 annotation forms.
Values which has "composed Object" doesn't set default.
I have attached my code.

Why form doesn't set value in MetaContent Object rows? What I'm doing wrong?
In controller when I wrote 
"echo $category->getMetaContent()->getMetaDescription();" it showed right value

```html
<?php

namespace Application\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Zend\Form\Annotation;

/**
 * BlogCategory
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="blog_category", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="category_parent_idx", columns={"parent_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 * 
 * @Annotation\Hydrator("Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ObjectProperty")
 * @Annotation\Name("Category")
 */
class BlogCategory
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     * 
     * @Annotation\Exclude()  
     */
    private $id;
    
     * @Annotation\Filter({"name":"StripTags"})
     * @Annotation\Required({"required":"true"})
     * @Annotation\Attributes({"class":"gui-input"})
     */
    private $name;
    
    
    /**
     * @var \Application\Entity\MetaContent
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\MetaContent", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="meta_content_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     * 
     * 
     * @Annotation\ComposedObject("Application\Entity\MetaContent")
     * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Meta content:", "label_options":{"class":"control-label"}})
     */
    private $metaContent;
```

```html
<?php

namespace Application\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Zend\Form\Annotation;

/**
 * MetaContent
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="meta_content")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * 
 * @Annotation\Name("MetaContent")
 */
class MetaContent
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     * 
     * @Annotation\Attributes({"type":"hidden"})
     * @Annotation\AllowEmpty(true)  
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="meta_description", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * 
     * @Annotation\Type("Zend\Form\Element\Text")
     * @Annotation\Required({"required":"true"})
     * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Meta description:"})
     * @Annotation\Validator({"name":"StringLength", "options":{"min":"5", "max":"255"}})
     * @Annotation\Filter({"name":"StripTags"})
     * @Annotation\Attributes({"class":"gui-input"})
     */
    private $metaDescription;
```

```html
use Zend\Form\Annotation\AnnotationBuilder;
 use DoctrineORMModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineEntity;

class IndexController extends AbstractAdminController { 

public function indexAction() {
        
        $em = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
        
        $view =  new ViewModel();
        
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        $category = $em->getRepository('Application\Entity\BlogCategory')->findOneByName('tests');
        $builder    = new AnnotationBuilder();
        $form       = $builder->createForm($category);
        
        $form->setHydrator(new DoctrineEntity($em, false));
        
        $form->add(array(
            'type' => 'submit',
            'name' => 'save',
            'attributes' => array(
                'value' => 'Submit',
            )
        ));
        
        $form->bind($category);
        $form->prepare();
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()){  
            $form->setData($data);
            if ($form->isValid()){               
                echo 'good!';
            }else{                
                echo 'bad';

            }
        }
        
        $view->setVariable('form', $form);
        return $view;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />        
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>Test</h1>
        
    {{form().openTag(form)|raw}}
    
    {{formCollection(form)}}
    
    {{form().closeTag()|raw}}

    </body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ve2qL.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, doctrine relations are lazy-loaded (proxied) - they're only loaded when items in the collection are actually accessed. This happens all behind the scenes, so when you do:

```
$category->getMetaContent(); 
// Collection is NOT loaded yet, it is a transparent PROXY

count($category->getMetaContent()); 
// In order to cound, we must load, 
// so only NOW the collection is loaded, replacing the PROXY

$category->getMetaContent()->getMetaDescription();
// Same here, only this command actually would load the MetaDescription

$category->getMetaContent()->getMetaDescription();
// Subsequent calls will return the MetaDescription directly, 
// as it already be been loaded
```

The last one is particulary important. Once the proxy has been replaced by the actual object, the object is always returned right away. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923817/what-is-a-proxy-in-doctrine-2) for more about proxies (recommended to read!)

Now things become are bit more difficult when using hydrators. During extraction, the reference returned by `getMetaContent` is the PROXY. But the `DoctrineEntity` hydrator doesn't resolve the proxy, but simply skips it as `un-extractable`. That is exactly what you're seeing here.

So why did it work in the first place when you had 
`$category->getMetaContent()->getMetaDescription();` in your controller? Because by this, the controller already made sure the proxy's been replaced by the actual object! Now the hydrator receives the actual object instead of the proxy - which it knows how to extract.

To counter this, you need to make sure that the proxy is actually resolved. You could do this by two simple ways:

- Tell doctrine to [EAGER load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26891658/what-is-the-difference-between-fetch-eager-and-fetch-lazy-in-doctrine) the relation. This will always load the `MetaDescription` object right away. Beware that this has a performance impact.
- Register a custom strategory with the hydrator that knows how to handle this field (i.e. extract it from a proxy). See [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142488/zend-framework-2-hydrator-strategy-for-doctrine-relationship-not-working) for the same issue/approach