# How to use hydrator with foreign key and show two entity attributes on a view in ZF2

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

I want to list on a view something like

> Number Commands  |  Date of commands  |  Description (text from table article)

All I have is

> Number Commands  |  Date of commands  |  Description (id from table Bc)

I have two tables: BC (as commands) which have columns: id_commands, id_article, id_user, number_commands, date_commands, ...
and  table Article which have columns : id_article, name_article, description_article, ...

According to this tutorial, [How to extend the ZF2 skeleton application - entities with foreign keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15827905/how-to-extend-the-zf2-skeleton-application-entities-with-foreign-keys#new-answer)

There are my codes:

On Bc\Model\Bc.php

```
class Bc implements BcInterface
{
...
     public function setArticle(ArticleInterface $bc_article)
     {
         $this->article = $bc_article;
     }

     public function getArticle()
     {
          return $this->bc_article;
     }
}
```

On Bc\Mapper\BcHydrator.php

```
namespace Bc\Mapper;

class BcHydrator // extends Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods
{
    public function extract($object)
    {
         return array(
             'bc_id'   => $object->getBc_id(),
             'article_designation' => $object->getA_designation(),
             'article_reference' => $object->getA_reference()
         );
    }

}
```

On Bc\Mapper\ZendDbSqlMapper.php

```
...
    public function findAllWithArticle()
        {
            $sql = new Sql($this->dbAdapter);
            $select = $sql  ->  select()
                            ->  from(   array('a'=>'s_article'))
                            ->  join(   array('bc' => 's_bc'),
                                        'bc.bc_id_article = a.a_id');
                            
    
            $stmt = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
            $result = $stmt->execute();
    
            if ($result instanceof ResultInterface && $result->isQueryResult()) {
                $resultSet = new HydratingResultSet($this->hydrator, $this->bcPrototype);
    
                \Zend\Debug\Debug::dump($result);die();
                //return $resultSet->initialize($result);
            }
            
            return array();
        }
```

On my Controller

```
...
public function detailAction()
    {
        $id = $this->params()->fromRoute('id');
        
        try {
            //$bc = $this->bcService->findBc($id);
            $bc = $this->bcService->findAllBcsWithArticle($id);
            $articleDesignation = $bc->getArticle()->getA_designation();
            
        } catch (\InvalidArgumentException $ex) {
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('bc');
        }
        
        return new ViewModel(array(
            'bc' => $bc,
            'article' => $articleDesignation
        ));
    }
```

I have this error, when I have access to my view:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
> Zend\Db\ResultSet\HydratingResultSet::getArticle()

Did someone have an idea of what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found a solution for those who want to know.
I didn't use hydrator, but i have the result i want.

1. Add on my class Bc (Bc\Model\Bc.php) a protected variable $description and set setter and getter.
2. On my Mapper (Bc\Mapper\ZendDbSqlMapper.php), i added a function findContent ($id), and use as sql request:

> ```
> $sql = new Sql($this->dbAdapter);     $select = $sql  ->  select()
>     ->    from(   array('bc'=>'bc'))
>     ->    join(   array('a' => 'article'),
>         'bc.bc_id_article = a.id',
>         array(
>             'description' => 'description',
>         ));
> $select->where(array('bc_id = ?' => $id));
> ```

3. On my service (Bc\Service\BcService.php)

> ```
> public function findBcsContent($id)
>     {
>         return $this->bcMapper->findContent($id);
>     }
> ```

4. And on my controller

> ```
> public function indexAction()
>         {
>              return new ViewModel(array(          
>                 'bcs'=> $this->bcService->findAllBcsContent()         
>              ));  
>         }
> ```

5. On my view, i could use

> `$this->escapeHtml($bc->getDesignation());`

That's all